# ADO Access Tab button

Tags: ms-access, ado, tabs

I moved my access apllication from DAO into ADO connection. It works better but I am encountering a problem when I enter a value in a form's field then I push the tab button 
the screen takes me to the first fields of the form and I lose my activecontrol which is the control of the field in which i enter the value.
N.B.: If I clicked the cursor using the mouse after applying the value in the specified field, it works properly...

Any help will highly appreciated

Comment: Just curious, how does your app work better with ADO?  What advantages did you get?

Comment: Can you show what events do you use in the form's field? If there're some, show us code, please.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found ADO to be better, simpler, faster code than DAO.

```
Dim rst as new ADODB.recordset
rst.open "Select * from employees", CnnString
```

I mean-- that's just less verbose than what you need in DAO.

Comment: How is that simpler than DAO? I can do this in DAO: `lngNewID = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENDITY")(0)` -- it's one line of code, whereas yours is two. I can open a DAO recordset in two lines of code, also: `Dim rs As DAO.Recordset / Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM employees;")`. DAO and ADO are different in the way you do things, but neither is more or less verbose than the other. The key difference is that when working with Jet/ACE data, DAO is a direct interface, the native interface, and supports more features and is faster.

Comment: When working with non-Jet/ACE data, the performance/features mix may or may not be completely different. And we programming outside of Access, it's very likely to be simpler to use ADO/OLEDB.